# Flutter: Background image is squeezing when keyboard appears

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Background image squeeze when the keyboard appears .

```
Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[

            Container(
              width:double.infinity ,
              height: double.infinity ,
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/bg.png')),
            Container(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(width*0.10),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: height*0.10,),
                      Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color:Colors.transparent),child: Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: height*0.02,left: 20.0,right: 20.0),child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),),),
                      SizedBox(height: height*0.05,),
                      Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
                          child: new Form(
                              key: _formKey,
                              autovalidate: _autoValidate,
                              child: LoginFrom(width,height))),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),


          ],
        )

    )
```

[image]

Comment: Please change the correct answer to @gbixahue's answer. This is the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just need to move the background image to become the parent widget. i.e

```
return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: ExactAssetImage('assets/images/bg.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  alignment:Alignment.topCenter,
                  ),     
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(width * 0.10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: height * 0.02, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                            child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.05,
                        ),
                        Container(
                            decoration:
                                BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
                            child: Container()
                            new Form(
                                key: _formKey,
                                autovalidate: _autoValidate,
                                child: LoginFrom(width, height))
                                ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )) // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
```

Comment: Still squeezing backgorund

Comment: @farhana, my bad I missed out the BoxFit code. See updated answer :)

Comment: i change `fit: BoxFit.fill` now it is working and i also update your code

Comment: not sure why this is no longer working

Answer (score 55):

Or you should use a Scaffold parameter

> resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false

```
Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
   body: (your_code)
)
```

Comment: this is works for me and I think it's the best solution so far..., thank u

Answer (score 5):

If Layout of you contain TextField inside ScrollView then `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` makes you unable to `scroll`.
You can do this to fix it:

Wrap the `Scaffold` with `Container`. After make the background color of `Scaffold` to transparent.

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,

   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
   )),

   child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    body: Container(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
     child: SingleChildScrollView(
-----------SingleChildScrollView with TextField-------------
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` property to Scaffold.

to Scaffold

```
 Scaffold(
       resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
       body: BodyWidget
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
height = max(height, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      image: imageProvider,
    ),
  ),
  height: height,
  child: Scaffold(...),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both of them(BG image, front) in SingleChildScrollView will do the trick

Comment: I see you are new here
Please add code snippet or more detail when answering questions

Answer (score 0):

resizeToAvoidBottomPadding = false resolve with set this property in scaffold.

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
)
```

Comment: That property does not exists.